# mantis is installed but unable to locate it for configuration

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I tried installing  [mantisBT [image: Install mantis]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mantis/) bug tracker with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mantis
```

and got the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mantis is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to configure it further, or even where it is located. I tried doing the following.

```
$ mantis
mantis: command not found
$ which mantis
$
```

I am new to Ubuntu installation. What should I try next to get this package running?

Answer (score 0):

`mantis` is not a desktop application.It is a web application,you can open it through **web browser**.See [this](http://www.mantisbt.org/manual/manual.installation.php) page for,how to configure *mantis*.